# Unable to upload image into AWS. Is there a S3 bucket config issue?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

New to Apostrophe and I have been following the install guide for servers. I have most things setup and the server is running on Heroku. I've setup the APOS_S3 environment variables but whenever I try to upload an image a entry is generated but when I go to the image URL, I get an error stating key does not exist. I check my bucket and I see that nothing has been uploaded either.

I've tried giving read/write object permissions publicly and it still isn't able to upload. I'm using my root account's Secret and Key as well for the APOS_S3_ variables.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Link to the error message:
http://ericmylesbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/attachments/cizbevhyl00070hucjclh9fto-sapling-1.full.jpg

Comment: Are you seeing broken images in the media library or do the images show up there? Getting any errors from Apostrophe? Your symptoms are consistent with the environment variables not actually being visible to Apostrophe. That would explain the files not being in the bucket at all. But then you would see them, at least temporarily, via local storage in Heroku, although that's not something you can rely on lasting through restarts so you do need to solve this if you want to use Heroku.

Comment: I'm only seeing broken images in the media library. Node is not coming up with any errors but I'm getting a 404 error when I upload. Does apostrophe save logs somewhere? I'm not certain of where to find any errors if there are any.

Comment: I just checked, and it seems like all my files are being saved locally but the library thinks it's in some AWS link. How would I go about making environment variables visible to Apostrophe? I've actually added the process.env.APOS_S3=<bucket stuff> to the app.js file.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a project I'm allowed to see on github? Obviously you will want to replace all the S3 settings with XXXXX.